# Infinite Loop, not certain as to why

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to take a text based game and make a GUI application with it. It is a number guessing game, where the computer chooses a number between 1 and 100. The user is expected to guess the correct number in the least amount of tries as possible.

My problem is that I am getting into an infinite loop when and I am not sure why or how to correct it.

The application is below:

```
# Guess My Number
#
# The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
# The player tries to guess it and the computer lets the player know
# if the guess is too high, too low or right on the money

from tkinter import *
from random import randint


class Application(Frame):
    """ A GUI Application for a number guessing game """
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.the_number = randint(1, 100)
        self.guess_ent = Entry(self)
        self.results = None
        self.tries = 1
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self,
              text="Welcome to 'Guess My Number'"
              ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        Label(self,
              text="I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100"
              ).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        Label(self,
              text="Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible"
              ).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        Label(self,
              text="What is your guess: "
              ).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.guess_ent.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        Button(self,
               text="Submit Guess",
               command=self.guessing
               ).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
        root.bind("<Return>", self.guessing_a)

        self.results = Label(self, text="")
        self.results.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

    def guessing(self):
        guess = int(self.guess_ent.get())
        while guess != self.the_number:
            if guess > self.the_number:
                self.results.config(text="Lower")
                self.guess_ent.delete(0, END)
            else:
                self.results.config(text="Higher")
                self.guess_ent.delete(0, END)

            self.tries += 1
            if self.tries >= 10:
                self.results.config(text="I'm sorry you couldn't guess the "
                                     "number in the appropriate amount "
                                     "of tries. The number I was "
                                     "thinking of was: {}"
                                .format(self.the_number))

    self.results.config(text="You guessed it!. "
                             "The number I was thinking of was: {}, "
                             "and it only took you {}, tries"
                        .format(self.the_number, self.tries))

    def guessing_a(self):
        self.guessing()

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Guess My Number")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: once you enter the while loop, you never update `guess`, `guess` doesn't magically update as the user types.

Comment: I added another `self.guess = int(self.guess_ent.get())` inside the while loop right before the `self.tries += 1` and get the same results. 
This is now exactly as I had it for the text based version of the game which is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of your code `root.mainloop()` means you already have a `while` loop in your program. So running a `while` loop inside an other one the way you did will lead to problems.

So the idea is to take an advantage of the main *implicit* while loop of your program and use it to increment the number of tries `self.tries` by one. This is in reality what is naturally when you used the `command` option of your button and the `bind()` method for <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I think you will understand the solution below easily.

Thus in the below program I modified only `guessing()` method and ... one last thing: do not forget to inject an event as a parameter to   def `guessing_a()` method otherwise pressing on <kbd>Enter</kbd> will raise a `TypeError` exception.

## Program

Here is the full program that works correctly both with pressing the button widget or the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keyboard button:

```
# Guess My Number
#
# The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
# The player tries to guess it and the computer lets the player know
# if the guess is too high, too low or right on the money

from tkinter import *
from random import randint


class Application(Frame):
    """ A GUI Application for a number guessing game """
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.the_number = randint(1, 100)
        self.guess_ent = Entry(self)
        self.results = None
        self.tries = 1
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self,
              text="Welcome to 'Guess My Number'"
              ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        Label(self,
              text="I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100"
              ).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        Label(self,
              text="Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible"
              ).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        Label(self,
              text="What is your guess: "
              ).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.guess_ent.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        Button(self,
               text="Submit Guess",
               command=self.guessing
               ).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
        root.bind("<Return>", self.guessing_a)

        self.results = Label(self, text="")
        self.results.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

    def guessing(self):
       if self.guess_ent.get() !='': # if there is a number in the entry widget. You can also improve this by checking if the entered text is a valid number
        guess = int(self.guess_ent.get())
        if guess > self.the_number:
                self.results.config(text="Lower")
                self.guess_ent.delete(0, END)
        elif guess < self.the_number:
                self.results.config(text="Higher")
                self.guess_ent.delete(0, END)
        else:
            self.results.config(text="You guessed it!. "
                             "The number I was thinking of was: {}, "
                             "and it only took you {}, tries"
                        .format(self.the_number, self.tries))    

        self.tries += 1
        if self.tries >= 10:
               self.results.config(text="I'm sorry you couldn't guess the "
                                     "number in the appropriate amount "
                                     "of tries. The number I was "
                                     "thinking of was: {}"
                                .format(self.the_number))

        
    def guessing_a(self, event):
        self.guessing()

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Guess My Number")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You can define `guessing` as `def guessing(self, event=None)` and then use it both for the command and the binding, eliminating the need for `guessing_a`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a while loop that check `while guess != self.number`. But, where do you change `guess`? This condition will always be true -> infinite loop.

You want guess inside the while loop.

Also, in Tk you shouldn't use a while loop, unless you're using threads. This is going to block the GUI. Use the `after` method instead.

Comment: the guess is right above the while loop where I get it from the guess_ent box. `guess = int(self.guess_ent.get())`

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem

Comment: Yeah not helpful, what is the problem. I am getting the guess from the user input. Then comparing it in the while loop. It worked in the text based game I am basing this off of?